# Unity, VMWare Workstation and the Super (Windows) key

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, launcher, vmware

I frequently run Windows 7 and Mac OS X as guest OS in VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu 11.10. Whenever I hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows) key in Windows/Mac OS the Unity launcher is activated. Even if I'm running VMWare fullscreen. This is really annoying. Is there any way to tell Compiz/Unity/etc to ignore the <kbd>Super</kbd> key while VMWare is focused? I know I could change Unity to use another key but I'd like to be able to use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key if possible when I'm not working in VMWare.

Comment: A couple of bug reports to get you started: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/unity/+bug/704231 (claimed fixed?) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/806255; I know it annoys me, using VirtualBox.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about those bug reports. I'll keep my eyes on the last one.

Comment: Same problem occurs when using [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) - Unity launcher is activated even if the focus is on a remote screen. Related post: http://superuser.com/questions/386921

Answer (score 3):

Copying out @Chris Morgan's comment as an answer to get this off the unanswered list.  @ntherning already posted a workaround in his question.

A couple of bug reports to get you started:

- http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/unity/+bug/704231 (claimed fixed?)
- http://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/806255